# Como puedo obenter mi edad a travez de una consulta en sql WORBENCH

Tags: sql, mariadb

Cuando ejecuto esta consulta

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(sysdate()- fecha_nacimiento) from personas;
```

obtengo este error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') from personas' at line 1

Comment: Cuál es el problema con esa consulta? Cómo está definida la tabla personas?

Comment: Bueno me funciona en mi manejador de sql developer de oracle pero en el de sql workbench cambia creo y por eso me sale error

Comment: quisiera saber como puedo solucionarlo

Comment: Es decir que estás probando algo en Oracle, funciona, y luego pruebas en MySQL y no funciona? QUé error sale? Por favor, añade la información completa [editando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/385400/edit) tu pregunta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') from personas' at line 1

Comment: Me sale ese error

Comment: **De nuevo**: EDITA tu pregunta e indica cómo está definida la tabla personas. Segundo intento. Revisa todo lo que puse en los comentarios. Además, TRUNCATE no funciona en Oracle, si acaso será TRUNC pero tampoco tienes todos los parámetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el campo `fecha_nacimiento` es tipo date, puedes utilizar `TIMESTAMPDIFF` y obtendrás el resultado que necesitas, algo así:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,fecha_nacimiento, NOW()) from personas;
```

Te dejo un ejemplo:
<kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2570487c89aea9b3857ffc685ef34b5b)</kbd>